# Java to JavaScript Type Conversion Algorithm

Tags: javascript, java, algorithm, graph

I have the following function that I would like to translate to JS (I am still new to JS, so having some difficulty):

It takes a complete graph of N nodes and enumerates all the unique pair matchings.

```
/**
*
* @param nodes The nodes still to be added to our edge list.
* @param edges The current edge list. This is mutated, so always return a clone!
*/
public static <N> List<Map<N,N>> enumerateEdges(List<N> nodes,Map<N,N> edges){
  if(nodes.isEmpty()) // No more nodes to create edges from, so return our current edge list in a new list.
    return Collections.singletonList(new HashMap<>(edges));


  N start = nodes.get(0); //The start node of our next pair.

  List<Map<N,N>> acc = new LinkedList<>(); //The accumulation of the EdgeLists

  for(int i = 1; i<nodes.size(); ++i){
    N end = nodes.get(i); //The end node of our pair
    edges.put(start,end); //Add this pair to our edge list

    List<N> unused = new ArrayList<>(nodes); // The nodes not used in our edge list.
    unused.remove(i);
    unused.remove(0);

    acc.addAll(enumerateEdges(unused,edges));

    edges.remove(start); //Remove this pair from our edge list.
  }

  return acc;
}
```

Called with:

```
List<Map<Integer,Integer>> results = enumerateEdges(Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3),new HashMap<>());
```

My current attempt at this doesn't work. It outputs empty arrays when doing a `console.log()`.

```
function enumerateEdges(nodes, edges) {
  if (nodes.length == 0) return [];

  let start = nodes[0];

  let acc = [];

  for(let i = 1; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    let end = nodes[i];

    edges = [ {start,end} ];

    let unused = nodes.slice(0);
    unused.splice(i,1);
    unused.splice(0,1);

    acc.push.apply(acc, enumerateEdges(unused,edges));

    edges.splice(0, 1);
  }
  return acc;
}
```

Calling this with:

```
let nodes = [1,2,3,4];
let edges = [];
enumerateEdges(nodes, edges);
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Much appreciated.

Comment: `.splice()` is not a replacement for `.remove()` because it does not modify the array; it *returns* a new array.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but also I've noticed that the `acc.push.apply(acc, enumerateEdges(unused,edges))` doesn't actually push edges to `acc`

Comment: @Pointy, `splice` *does* mutate the array like `remove` does.

Comment: @cyberkronos, the `push.apply` works, but the function result is always an empty array, because that is what you return (by error) in the first `if` statement.

Comment: @trincot oops you're right; I was thinking about `.slice()` :) One little "p".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issues are:

- The end point of the recursion (when `nodes.length == 0`) should not return an empty array, but a copy of the *edges* array
- `edges = [ {start,end} ]` completely overwrites whatever was in `edges` before. You need to `push` the pair on it. Furthermore
- `edges.splice(0, 1)` removes the first element, but in the original code it must remove the element keyed by *start*, which in practice is the last element in the *edges* list.

Note that JavaScript has a `Map` constructor which you could use for `edges`, so it would be much like how the Java code works. But in this case I find its use overkill: an array will just work fine. I added the version using Map in a second snippet.

**Edit:** I would also suggest to change the condition `length == 0` to `length < 2`, so the thing doesn't get into trouble when you pass it an odd number of nodes.

```js
function enumerateEdges(nodes, edges) {
  if (nodes.length < 2) return [...edges]; // return copy
  let start = nodes[0];
  let acc = [];
  for(let i = 1; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    let end = nodes[i];
    edges.push({start, end}); // don't overwrite, but push 
    let unused = nodes.slice(0);
    unused.splice(i,1);
    unused.splice(0,1);
    // The spread operator will put each of the array elements as separate arguments
    // ... so no more need for the mysterious apply:
    acc.push(...enumerateEdges(unused, edges));
    edges.pop(); // in practice it is always the last element to be removed
  }
  return acc;
}

let nodes = [1,2,3,4];
let edges = [];
let result = enumerateEdges(nodes, edges);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For fun, here is a highly condensed version of it:

```js
function enumerateEdges(nodes, edges) {
  return nodes.length < 2 ? edges
        : nodes.reduce( (acc, end, i) => (i<2 ? [] : acc).concat(
            enumerateEdges(nodes.slice(1, i).concat(nodes.slice(i+1)), 
                           [...edges, {start:nodes[0], end}])
          ) );
}

let nodes = [1,2,3,4];
let edges = [];
let result = enumerateEdges(nodes, edges);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Alternative with Map:

```js
function enumerateEdges(nodes, edges) {
  if (nodes.length < 2) return [...edges]; // return copy
  let start = nodes[0];
  let acc = [];
  for(let i = 1; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    let end = nodes[i];
    edges.set(start, end); // <-- Map method to add
    let unused = nodes.slice(0);
    unused.splice(i,1);
    unused.splice(0,1);
    // The spread operator will put each of the array elements as separate arguments
    // ... so no more need for the mysterious apply:
    acc.push(...enumerateEdges(unused, edges));
    edges.delete(start); // <-- Map method to remove
  }
  return acc;
}

let nodes = [1,2,3,4];
let edges = new Map(); // <-- use Map
let result = enumerateEdges(nodes, edges);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Note that the edges are now output as simple pair-arrays, like `[1, 2]`, instead of `{start: 1, end: 2}`. This can of course be changed, but I left it like this -- it is the default way on how Maps are translated to arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Helps a lot.

Comment: I have a follow up question. Would this be scalable for say 100 nodes instead of 4. Is there were you can use a Map function instead?

Comment: I added a snippet that uses a Map. I don't think it matters much for scaling. I also adapted the test for `length == 0` which would be problematic when the graph has an odd number of nodes. I do wonder however: the output puts all found edges in a flat array, without grouping them per configuration. From what I understand of the Java code, it is like that also in the Java version (`addAll`). You may want to change that.